# Deleting event from iCal not working when iCal is not in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Am trying to delete the event from iCal as soon as I get the notification. The event is getting deleted only if iCal is in background. If the same notification is sent after closing iCal, the event is not deleted. Am trying to access iCal using this method in MyCalendar.m

```
+ (void)requestAccess:(void (^)(BOOL granted, NSError *error))callback {
  if (eventStore == nil) {
    eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
  }
  [eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:callback];
}
```

And am trying to delete the event using following method in Appdelegate.m

```
[MyCalendar requestAccess:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
            if (granted) {
                if ([[self.launchOptions objectForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"remainder"] || [[self.launchOptions objectForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"cancelAppointment"]) {
                    if ([[self.launchOptions objectForKey:@"type"]
                         isEqualToString:@"cancelAppointment"]) {
                        if (![MyCalendar removeEventWithEventIdentifier:
                              [self.launchOptions objectForKey:@"eventId"]]) {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
       }];
```

Am deleting the event from iCal using following method in MyCalendar.m

```
+ (BOOL)removeEventWithEventIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier {
  EKEvent *event2 = [eventStore eventWithIdentifier:identifier];
  BOOL result = NO;
  if (event2 != nil) {
    NSError *error = nil;
    result = [eventStore removeEvent:event2 span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error];
  }
  return result;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialize the event store object before using.

```
    + (BOOL)removeEventWithEventIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier {
        EKEventStore* eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
        EKEvent *event2 = [eventStore eventWithIdentifier:identifier];
        BOOL result = NO;
        if (event2 != nil) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        result = [eventStore removeEvent:event2 span:EKSpanThisEvent        error:&error];
        }
      return result;
      }
```